# Call caldera form ID in a wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to show the number of entries in a wordpress caldera form form on the front page. I've gotten it to work when i paste the shortcode within the form itself, but I don't know how to call the form when i'm just placing the shortcode in a page. How do I call the specific form id?

```
add_shortcode('cf_entries', 'mc_cfes_output');

function mc_cfes_output($atts) {
  
    global $wpdb;
                $total = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `total` FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "cf_form_entries` WHERE `form_id` = %s && `status` = 'active';", $form_id));
  echo $total;
        }
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to just pass the form ID as a shortcode attributes to the `cf_entries` shortcode?

Comment: Could you help me with what that would look like?